# Unable to retrieve incoming phone number via Twilio REST API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I created a Twilio Connect app and gave it permissions using my account. I have already bought a phone number via my account (not via the API).

I tried retrieving the phone number via the API.

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = '<account_sid received via the authorize endpoint callback>'

auth_token  = '<my_auth_token>'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 

client.incoming_phone_numbers.list() 

[] # Empty list
```

Expected result - the phone number that I have already bought

Actual result   - empty list

Comment: I would expect that too. Are you able to perform other actions on behalf of the account, like send or list messages?

Comment: I couldn't try that since I was not able to access the phone numbers. I got a reply from support stating that most third party apps ask the users to copy-paste the SID, token and phone number. That's a shame because Connect seemed to be the "right" way to go here since it required minimal user input.